# What GC date was the Exodan Fleet discovered by the Aeluons

Tags: wayfarers

In Becky Chambers *Wayfarers* series the Human Exodan Fleet is found by the Galactic Commons at some point far enough in the past for Humans to have

1. Spread across most of the GC subsequently
2. Be able to refer to Great Great Great Great Grandparents being from the fleet.
3. References to GC admittance talk about the need for GC to provide charity.

But it is only GC year 309. This doesn't seem very long.

Comment: Your second point has 7 generations (if I'm reading it right), this family had 6 generations of a family alive at the same time. With the oldest being 103 years old, so a 7 generation family could probably exist in 100-150 years BBC News - Meet the British family spanning six generations
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-38704598

Comment: How long before the findng of the Fleet was the Galactic Commons founded?  Maybe the Galacic Commons wa founded 100 years before the fleet was discovered, whch would be make the discovery 209 years in the past by GC 309.  And how long are GC years?